# Drupal 7 и сессии

Tags: php, drupal

Мне нужно удалять сессию пользователя после закрытия браузера. 
В конфиге прописаны такие строки:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1440);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
```

Последний параметр должен удалять сессию, при закрытии браузера, но этого не происходит. В какую сторону копать?

P.S. Идентификатор сессии в куках отмечен как "сессия", т.е. он должен удаляться. Но этого тоже не происходит.

Comment: Браузер - это хром?

Comment: Да. Кстати, при setcookie с expire = 0 - тоже сохраняет даже после закрытия.

Comment: Насколько знаю, это поведение хрома - корректное завершение у него не означает завершение сессии, он просто дампает ее на диск.

Comment: а есть какое-то решение универсальное?

Comment: Хз. Разве вам действительно нужно отслеживать момент закрытия браузера?

Comment: Нужно сбрасывать данные после закрытия сайта.

Comment: Ну, это уже серьезно выпадает из закрытия браузера. Вы не сможете достоверно определить этот момент, для более-менее удобоваримого результата вам надо подсчитывать количество активных вкладок с сайтом через js и слать AJAX-запрос после закрытия последней (событие onunload), в общем, вы не сможете поймать этот момент ни с околостопроцентной вероятностью, ни малыми усилиями. Можно еще пинговать каждые N минут, но банальная минутная проблема с интернетом опять же будет рушить всю систему. HTTP вообще в принципе так не работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделайте 2-й Ваш комментарий ответом, я его приму как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сессионные куки (с expire = session) удаляются не по закрытию по браузера, а по закрытию сессии. Это довольно размытое явление, которое может трактоваться создателем бразера как угодно, и, например, в хроме сессия продолжается даже между выключениями (сохраняется на диск и восстанавливается еще раз). Таким образом, выставление сессионных кук, в том числе и PHPSESSION, не гарантирует их удаление при закрытии браузера.

Оптимальным вариантом считаю выставить время жизни куки в среднее время, после которого пользователя можно считать "ушедшим". ЕМНИП, при каждом запросе PHP будет обновлять PHPSESSION-куку, обновляя вместе с тем и время ее жизни.